# Auotmated Data Updates to Salesforce

Tags: web-services, salesforce

I am working on a website's internal applications and what we want to do is to programmatically update our sales force data via api.  For example, to update some entities on a a cronjob etc.

Generally this seems to imply the need for an admin type user that can acquire an access token and make REST Api calls.  We could go about doing that, however, salesforce requires a password change every 60 days. How can I get purely programmatic access to our salesforce account?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that it is a best practise to set up a dedicated API/Integration user. You can make a permission set with the "Password Never Expires"  system permission enabled. Add that to your integration user and you're good to go.